# I cannot use opencv and numpy in conda environment

Tags: python, conda

I am using M1 Macbookpro(Monterey 12.6). After the removement of python@3.9 and its pip in brew, the numpy and opencv modules do not work rightly anymore in conda base or any other environments.

```
brew uninstall python@3.9
```

[enter image description here][1]

It seems Okay. However, the opencv and numpy packages are not able to be imported correctly.

```
Python 3.9.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, May 27 2022, 17:01:00)
[Clang 13.0.1 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
OpenCV bindings requires "numpy" package.
Install it via command:
pip install numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from . import multiarray
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
from . import overrides
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
import numpy
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
from . import core
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

* The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/pyFDTD/bin/python"
* The NumPy version is: "1.23.3"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

The log asked me to install numpy via pip and I did it.

```
pip install numpy
```

The result shows that I did install numpy with correct version.

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.23.3)
```

All modules work in right ways when I am using the global python and pip. In this conda environment, python is located in the right directory.

```
❯ which python
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/pyFDTD/bin/python
❯ which pip
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/pyFDTD/bin/pip
```

How to fix the problem? Is something wrong with the conda or pip?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWsYO.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n26B.png

Comment: If you are on an M1 or M2, NumPy may struggle to compile correctly everything when `pip`-installing it. Perhaps you could try installing it via `conda`

Comment: Thank you. But the global python out of conda is able to import numpy correctly. I have removed the conda so that my terminal could recognize the right python interpreter and it works well.